# postgresql insert while updating table

Tags: postgresql, insert, sql-update

I have a large table and I start Update query for all rows:

```
UPDATE <table> SET column1 = column1 - interval '3 hours'
```

And this query is running a long time (18 hours).
**So while this query is running I need to insert new rows in this table.**
Will it be a conflict? Will update query try to update new rows? (I don't want it)

Also I try to select in  this table to check how many rows already was updated.
And it seems that minimum of rows.

Will Postgres update it all at the end or it should updating continuously and I should see changes by selecting?

If I cancel an update query, is it right that some rows should be updated and some not?
And if it's right, is postgres update it in order by growing id, or it is random?

Comment: Of course you can insert new rows while an update is running. What makes you think you can't? And as long as your UPDATE is running (and thus the changes are not committed) you can't see the changes from other sessions.

Comment: How big is that table anyway? 18 Hours for such an update sounds more like your update is waiting for some locks. You should check the system view `pg_stat_activity` to see if you query is actually doing something or simply sitting there waiting to obtain a row lock.

Comment: Well, a table contains 40.000.000 rows and 70 columns (but I update only 1 column). I try check if there is a locks by: `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;` and it's empty. Also I checked a `pg_stat_activity` and it shows only update query (which exist more than 5 min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. PostgreSQL will usually update the rows in physical order, that is in “random” order for you (because the physical order can change any time).
2. The `UPDATE` won't block concurrent `INSERT`s.
3. The `UPDATE` will only process rows that have been committed at the time it started, so it won't affect any newly added rows.
4. The modified rows will not be not visible for concurrent sessions until the updating transaction ends.
5. If you interrupt the `UPDATE`, all its effects are undone.

All these (except the first one) are properties of database transactions at the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level; you may want to read up about [concurrency control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) in the documentation.